# Apple push notification with php

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

Hi i have a PHP script to send push notifications to devices through apple push notification server. I want to know is there any way of setting apple push notification with a certain time that apple sends the push notification to device when the time happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. The notification will be pushed to the device as soon as possible. You can see all the possible parameters you can send [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html). If you want to schedule it for a certain time, you'll have to do that on your server and push it to Apple at that time.